# What resistor should be connected to a $12\,\rm{V}$ battery for a $9\,\rm{V}$ output?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

I have a $12\,\rm{V}$ car battery and a $9\,\rm{V}$ toy piano. I want to power the piano through the battery but the voltage is too high. What resistance should be connected to this circuit so that the piano receives only $9\,\rm{V}$?

[image: Circuit Diagram]

In the given diagram $r$ is the resistance of the piano and $R$ is the unknown resistance connected in series with the battery.

Since this is a simple series circuit the current $I$ is constant throughout the circuit and given by:
$$-Ir-IR+12=0$$
$$12=I(r+R)$$
$$I=\frac{12}{r+R}$$

The potential difference across the piano should be $9\,\rm{V}$ and so
$$V_{\rm{piano}}=Ir$$
$$V_{\rm{piano}}=\frac{12}{r+R}r$$
$$V_{\rm{piano}}r+V_{\rm{piano}}R=12r$$
$$9r+9R=12r$$
$$9R=3r$$
$$R=\frac{r}{3}$$

So according to my calculations, a resistance of $r/3$ should be connected for a voltage of $9\,\rm{V}$ across the piano. Is this right or did I just do everything wrong?

Also I measured the resistance across the piano and it turned out to be about $170\,\rm{k\Omega}$, so isn't a resistor of $5.6\,\rm{k\Omega}$ excessively large? This just seems wrong. I need to know why.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is not actually a homework exercise. I actually want to do this at home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculation is correct, it's a voltage divider. (R+r)/r = 12/9, supposing that it's 17k and 5.6k. But the piano may have a varying resistance, for example if more tones are played simultaneously. Also the acoustic energy depends on the frequency. And the car's alternator has a variable output up to ca. 14.4 Volt. So it's better to take a LM7809 voltage regulator and 2 capacitors to ensure always the same sound /frequency - otherwise it might become some kind of torture equipment for the listeners. Another point is the measurement of the piano's resistance. If done with a multimeter in the resistance position, the value is of no use, since the measurement voltage may be much lower than the 9 Volt. A far better solution would be to measure the current of the piano if fed with 9 Volt and calculating the resistance.

Comment: "If done with a multimeter in the resistance position, the value is of no use, since the measurement voltage may be much lower than the 9 Volt. A far better solution would be to measure the current of the piano if fed with 9 Volt and calculating the resistance." I don't understand what this means. Why would the resistance value be of no use?

Comment: The piano electronic is completely different from an ohmic resistor, i.e. it is strictly non-linear. If provided with 0.5 Volt, the current may be zero resulting in infinite resistance since many chips inside won't work. With 500 V, the electronics may burn resulting in a shortcut, so the equivalent resistor will be nearly zero Ohm. Only the working  voltage of 9 Volt will deliver the correct equivalent resistor.

Comment: Also, how does it make sense that if the resistance of the piano were any larger, I would have to connect an even larger resistor? Wouldn't there come a point where the external resistance would be so large that no current would flow through the piano?

Comment: Even if the piano's resistance is measured at 9 Volt, it is only valid for the momentary status of the piano. If no key is pressed, it may go into a battery saver or stand by mode, i.e. a very tiny current flows. An equivalent resistor would be very large, and R  three times larger. If many keys are pressed during the measurement, a smaller equivalent resistor will be measured. That's also a reason why a resistor is not a good solution in this case. A better solution would  be 4 diodes in series, f.e. any SI diode that has a maximal current at least as high as the maximal current of the piano.